# QFileDialog encoding error (Windows 7)

Tags: qt, encoding, qfiledialog

When i try to use standart filechooser:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(a.allWidgets().first(),
     "Open Image", "C:\\", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)");
```

the error is appear. I see the message, like this (sorry, it's in russian):

[image]

the translation of first line is "C:\Users\Василий\Desctop references an inaccessible location". I think, that problem in user-name "Василий" (russian letters), which not clearly written on screenshot. I have tried to find in Google the solving of my problem, but unfortunately, I haven't find. Help please.

Comment: You have specified "C:\\" as the default location, but the error refers to "C:\Users\Василий\Desktop" - did you navigate to this location, or did it go there immediately?

Comment: The error appear immediately, when appear the file browser. I think, that is bacause in windows 7 in the left column (in file browser) there is a link to "Desctop" location.

Comment: try "/home" instead of "C:\\"

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've faced the same problem. It seems like some bug in Qt, which causes this error, when the name of your home folder contains non-latin symbols.

Remarkable that if you run your application in **Release** mode, it will work fine. I hope this information will be useful for somebody.